# How to improve entity recognition?

Tags: spacy, spacy-3

I am using Spacy's named entity recognition with **it_core_news_lg** but getting low-quality output, e.g.

`{'Carlo Rossi?I', 'Carlo', 'Teresa Rossi', 'Pietro?', 'Bruno?Sì', 'Pietro Rossi', 'Pia', 'Maria', 'Pietro', 'Maria e Pia', 'Maria e', 'Bruno', 'Bruno Rossi', 'Rossi', 'Carlo Rossi'}`

instead of

`{'Carlo Rossi', 'Carlo', 'Teresa Rossi', 'Pietro', 'Bruno', 'Pietro Rossi', 'Pia', 'Maria', 'Pietro', 'Maria', 'Pia', 'Maria', 'Bruno', 'Bruno Rossi', 'Rossi', 'Carlo Rossi'}`

Is there anything I can do to improve/fix it?